# dropdown list <select> tag hide and sort order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select, dropdown

I am working on a soccer league website. I have two dropdown lists with criteria, the second dropdown is limited based on the first selection.

1. I want to hide options on the second dropdown list, by default it's showing all options. The options should be active only when I select an option from the first dropdown list.
2. The second dropdown picks the last option upon selecting an option from the first dropdown list, I need the second dropdown list to select the first option by default.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var allOptions = $('#dseason option')
 $('#ldivision').change(function() {
  $('#dseason option').remove()
  var classN = $('#ldivision option:selected').prop('class');
  var opts = allOptions.filter('.' + classN);
  $.each(opts, function(i, j) {
   $(j).appendTo('#dseason');
  });
 });

 //show content script
 $(document).ready(function() {
  //hides dropdown content
  $(".showcontent").hide();
  //unhides first option content
  $("#acd1s2014").show();
  //listen to dropdown for change
  $("#dseason").change(function() {
   //rehide content on change
   $('.showcontent').hide();
   //unhides current item
   $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
 });
 //close script

});
```

```css
/* dropdown selector */
select {
 font-family: verdana;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 5px;
 width: 200px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: border-bottom 2s;
}

select:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ldivision" name="divisionselected">
  <!-- selector name -->
  <option value="" class="dselect">Select Category</option>
  <!-- league season dropdown -->
  <option class="div01" value="Division 01">Division 01</option>
  <option class="div02" value="Division 02">Division 02</option>
</select>

<!-- spacing the selectors -->
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<select id="dseason" name="seasonselected">
  <!-- selector name -->
  <option value="" class="sselect">Select Product</option>
  <!-- league season option 01 -->
  <option value="acd1s2014" class="div01">Season 2014</option>
  <option value="acd1s2015" class="div01">Season 2015</option>
  <option value="acd1s2016" class="div01">Season 2016</option>
  <option value="acd1s2017" class="div01">Season 2017</option>
  <!-- league season option 02 -->
  <option value="acd2s2014" class="div02">Season 2014</option>
  <option value="acd2s2015" class="div02">Season 2015</option>
  <option value="acd2s2016" class="div02">Season 2016</option>
</select>

<!-- dropdown content option 01 -->
<div id="acd1s2014" class="showcontent">ac div 01 s 2014</div>
<div id="acd1s2015" class="showcontent">ac div 01 s 2015</div>
<div id="acd1s2016" class="showcontent">ac div 01 s 2016</div>
<div id="acd1s2017" class="showcontent">ac div 01 s 2017</div>
<!-- dropdown content option 02 -->
<div id="acd2s2014" class="showcontent">ac div 02 s 2014</div>
<div id="acd2s2015" class="showcontent">ac div 02 s 2015</div>
<div id="acd2s2016" class="showcontent">ac div 02 s 2016</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1754zgb/2/).

Thanks.

Comment: So what is your ***specific*** question? All you've done is posted your requirements.It sounds like you just want us to write the solution for the entire requirement for you. By the way, since you've posted your code here in a code snippet, there's no need to also link to a Fiddle.

Comment: I'm new to this, understood about the snippet part. How can I hide the options on the second dropdown list by default, currently it's showing the information without selecting and option on the first dropdown list?

Comment: Yes, you've said that. That's what you want to have happen. But, we expect that you'll make an attempt at a solution and then ask a specific question about a programming problem that you are encountering. If you want to know how to hide options in one list based on the selection of another in general, this is not the place. There are numerous tutorials on the web for such things. When you are ready to make an attempt, try it out and if you have problems with your attempt, come back here and post what you are doing and your specific problem.

Comment: Yes sir! point noted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this one :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       var allOptions = $('#dseason option');
       allOptions.hide();

       $('#ldivision').change(function() {
        
        $('#dseason option').remove();
        var classN = $('#ldivision option:selected').prop('class');
        var opts = allOptions.filter('.' + classN);

        $.each(opts, function(i, j) {
         $(j).appendTo('#dseason');
        });

        $('#dseason').val($('#dseason option:first').val());
        allOptions.show();

       });

       $(".showcontent").hide();
        //unhides first option content
        $("#acd1s2014").show();
        //listen to dropdown for change
        $("#dseason").change(function() {
         //rehide content on change
         $('.showcontent').hide();
         //unhides current item
         $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
       
      });
```

```css
/* dropdown selector */
select {
 font-family: verdana;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 5px;
 width: 200px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: border-bottom 2s;
}

select:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ldivision" name="divisionselected">
  <!-- selector name -->
  <option value="" class="dselect">Select Category</option>
  <!-- league season dropdown -->
  <option class="div01" value="Division 01">Division 01</option>
  <option class="div02" value="Division 02">Division 02</option>
</select>

<!-- spacing the selectors -->
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<select id="dseason" name="seasonselected">
  <!-- selector name -->
  <option value="" class="sselect">Select Product</option>
  <!-- league season option 01 -->
  <option value="acd1s2014" class="div01">Season 2014</option>
  <option value="acd1s2015" class="div01">Season 2015</option>
  <option value="acd1s2016" class="div01">Season 2016</option>
  <option value="acd1s2017" class="div01">Season 2017</option>
  <!-- league season option 02 -->
  <option value="acd2s2014" class="div02">Season 2014</option>
  <option value="acd2s2015" class="div02">Season 2015</option>
  <option value="acd2s2016" class="div02">Season 2016</option>
</select>

<!-- dropdown content option 01 -->
<div id="acd1s2014" class="showcontent">ac div 01 s 2014</div>
<div id="acd1s2015" class="showcontent">ac div 01 s 2015</div>
<div id="acd1s2016" class="showcontent">ac div 01 s 2016</div>
<div id="acd1s2017" class="showcontent">ac div 01 s 2017</div>
<!-- dropdown content option 02 -->
<div id="acd2s2014" class="showcontent">ac div 02 s 2014</div>
<div id="acd2s2015" class="showcontent">ac div 02 s 2015</div>
<div id="acd2s2016" class="showcontent">ac div 02 s 2016</div>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions that shouldn't be posted in the first place, it will only encourage more poor questions. Also, when you do post an answer, it should explain the problem and how it solved the problem and not just be "try this" along with code. You will find that even answers with correct solutions often get down voted because they don't inform anyone about what the code does. Remember, Stack Overflow is a knowledge base. It's not just about answering one person's question. It's also about providing information that others will find in the future.